# JVM Heap dumps of Keycloak running on kubernetes

Tags: jvm, keycloak

We have a Keycloak deployment running on Kubernetes. Our containers need to be periodically restarted because of high memory consumption. I want to analyze what is causing high memory consumption. How can I take JVM Heap dumps without modifying the Keycloak container image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can dump heap on demand with [`jmap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr014.html) command outside container.

You can also enable automatic heap dump on out of memory condition with `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` JVM flag. Add `-XX:HeapDumpPath` to specify the path where to store heap dumps. JVM options can be added without modifying container image; just add the following environment variable:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/storage/path"
```

Finally, since these JVM options are *manageable*, you can set them in runtime with [`jcmd`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html#BABEHABG):

```
jcmd <PID> VM.set_flag HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError true
jcmd <PID> VM.set_flag HeapDumpPath /storage/path
```

Comment: i had to use following    JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8790 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false  -Dquarkus-log-max-startup-records=10000 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8790 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/keycloak.hprof" and than was able to connect using VIsualVM